# How to get a bold matrix

Tags: matrices, bold

How can I typeset a matrix in bold?  I usually use bmatrix, so I tried

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, bm}

\begin{document}

\[ \bm{\begin{bmatrix}
      1 & 2
    \end{bmatrix} }\]

\end{document}
```

but it just hangs when I compile.

Comment: before the display, and preferably within a group so that it doesn't persist, issue the command `\boldmath`.  i'm not sure whether it will make the brackets bold, but the contents should be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can make an entire display bold using `\boldmath`.  this must be entered
outside of the display, so it's necessary to bury it in a group so that it won't
persist.  i recommend `\begingroup ... \endgroup`, but `{ ... }` is equally
effective, if not always as easy to spot.

if only *part* of a display should be bold, and `\bm` doesn't work, the part that
should be bold can be isolated within `\text{\boldmath $ ... $}`, adding
`\displaystyle` if necessary.

this example is a bit more complicated than necessary, but i wanted to show
the two methods, and also illustrate that the brackets are *not* made bold in
the process.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, bm}
\textwidth=.5\textwidth

\begin{document}
\noindent some text above the display.
\begingroup \boldmath
\[ \begin{bmatrix}
      1 & 2\\
      3 & 4
    \end{bmatrix} \]
\endgroup
text below the display; spacing check.
\[ \begin{bmatrix}
      1 & 2\\
      3 & 4
    \end{bmatrix}
 + \text{\boldmath
   $\begin{bmatrix}
      1 & 2\\
      3 & 4
    \end{bmatrix}$}
\]
and still more text.

\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]